# Adding Facebook Login to Own Website

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I'd like users on my site to be able to log in using their existing Facebook accounts.

I've downloaded the Facebook PHP SDK from [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com) and set up an app for my website. I just used the example.php file that came bundled with the sdk, and swapped out the numbers for the 'appID', and 'secret' of my app.

**NOTE: In code 'appID' and 'secret' are replacing the actual equivalent**

---

I have this is my header:

`require 'src/facebook.php';` (Which is definitely being found)

---

This is the code on the main page, where the login will be (also from example.php):

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'appID',
'secret' => 'secret',
));

var_dump($facebook);
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

echo "<br />";
var_dump($user);

if ($user) {
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
}

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');
?>

<?php var_dump($user); ?>


<h1>php-sdk</h1>

<?php if ($user): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo "LoginURL:"; var_dump($loginUrl);?>
<div>
 <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>

</div>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

<?php if ($user): ?>
<h3>You</h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

<h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
<strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
<?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
```

---

When I'm not logged into Facebook, and click the link, it takes me to a Facebook login page. After logging in, it then redirects back to the main site with new variables in the url (state, code, etc.). Once "logged" in, `var_dump($user)` just returns `int(0)`.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? I have no clue why it can't assign a user.

---

Result of dumping `$facebook`:

```
object(Facebook)#182 (9) { 
["sharedSessionID:protected"]=> NULL 
["appId:protected"]=> string(15) "appID" 
["appSecret:protected"]=> string(32) "secret" 
["user:protected"]=> NULL ["signedRequest:protected"]=> NULL 
["state:protected"]=> NULL ["accessToken:protected"]=> NULL 
["fileUploadSupport:protected"]=> bool(false) 
["trustForwarded:protected"]=> bool(false) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the Facebook connectivity such as posting as a user or anything like that. You may want to just look into the [register form iframe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) that you can get from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Its Happen to me and when i check my apache log i found this :

And i found its an SSL problems when communicate with Facebook via PHP SDK (using Curl). You have to set CURL_OPTS "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" to "false" .

Ex:

facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;